# SAN Storage shared disk, files copied from other servers cannot be seen without re-mounting

Tags: linux, storage-area-network, ext3

I have a SAN Storage connected to my servers using fibre HBA. Using multipath, I've successfully mapped the device, formatted it as ext3, and mount it to my file system.

But the problem is, the host can't see the files other hosts copy to the shared disk without re-mounting the device.

I'm using CentOS 6.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh my.

ExtN file systems are **not** cluster-aware file systems. They can only be mounted by a single system at a time.

OCFS2 and GFS2 are two widely-used clustered file systems.

If you truly need multiple systems mounting the same filesystem, then you will need to reformat with one of the above options.